# How do I question a witness with emotions instead of evidence?

Tags: phoenix-wright-dual-destinies

During the 5th case of *Ace Attorney: Dual Destinies*, you get an option to question a witness using either his testimony or his emotions. If you select testimony, Athena says she can switch back to looking for inconsistent emotions, but the only option I can see is to present evidence.

How do I switch back to questioning the witness with emotions instead of presenting evidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep advancing through the witness’s testimony past their final statement. Athena will then ask if you want to switch to analyzing emotions. This also works if you want to switch from analyzing emotions to presenting evidence.

(Technically you’ll also be prompted to switch if you present incorrect evidence, but this would result in a penalty)